# Add "IsXhr" Column to Chrome Dev Tools Network Console

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Are there any extensions that offer the ability to have a new column, is XHR, in the Network section of the chrome dev tools? If not, are there any examples of extending chrome to show a new column with it's value deduced to display whether a request is initiated through XHR or not?

*I know Chrome offers the ability to "log XMLHttpRequests" and to filter by "XHR." I'm looking for a column that displays whether the request is XHR; should be very simple, but haven't found a solution ...*

***note - this is a concern because I've enabled the "preserve log" option on the network tab in the chrome dev tools.***

Comment: Better still would be the ability to show any custom headers as a column, instead of the limited default list (http://ctrlv.in/315342)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a **type** column now that has the response type so `document` for the initial html request and also things like `script`, `stylesheet`, `png` `jpeg`... and it also has `xhr` for xhr requests.

[image]

You now can also add `Response Headers` and even create custom ones if the defaults are not sufficient (right-click somewhere on the column headings to reveal options).

[image]